# Is the time a transaction was done recorded in the block chain?

Tags: blockchain, protocol

Is there something like a timestamp of each transaction recorded in the block chain, or only the mere fact that the transaction was done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a unix timestamp in the block message. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#block

So you would be able to get know the transaction hit the blockchain down to roughly a 10 minute resolution.

Comment: I think the timestamp in the block can be off my more than 10 minutes.It can be manipulated by the miner finding the block within certain limits. Blocks are considered valid if their time is greater than the median of the last 11 blocks and less than currentTime + 2 hours.

Comment: Also, the transaction could have happened quite some time before a miner decided to include it.